# What is the best way to define "KEY" in React when creating a list with map function from an array which containing no unique ID or fields?

Tags: reactjs

What is the best way to define "KEY" in React when creating a list with map function from an array which containing no unique ID or any unique fields.
I don't want to go with index because If later any item remove or added in array previous array index will be change that does not helps React to keep track listing DOM nodes.
So how can I generate or define "KEY"(unique KEY) for DOM nodes?

Comment: you can use libraries like lodash https://github.com/typicode/react-lodash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible, convert it to an array of objects and have one of the key/value pairs be the id... Here is a little helper function to generate random ids:

```
const generateId = () => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)
```

Then use this function something like this:

```
const arr = [{ id: generateId(), name: 'Bob' }, { id: generateId(), name: 'Jane' }, { id: generateId(), name: 'Jack' }]
```

Comment: your are showing an awesome example to solve it.
I also thinking a similar way but instead of pushing extra fields in the array
Can I genarate key like  below process.

const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
    <li key={`${number.toString() } + ${Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10)}`}>
      {number}
    </li>
  );

Comment: is it possible ?

Comment: I'm thinking now you are right because If generate unique key
like my way then if array updated then previous key will be changed also. It's also not helpful for React
your previous way is the right.

Comment: @SubhajitPanja: I'm sorry but do not use this solution as pointed out here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/9816472

Comment: it will always force react to re-render each item in the list, even when this is not required. This a very bad solution as it greatly impacts performance. Not to mention that one cannot exclude the possibility of a key collision in the event that Math.random() produces the same number twice.

Comment: @Isaac Yes - good point... In the render it is problematic... Tried but no dice...

Comment: Hey @Isaac getting more confuse 
github.com/thearnica/react-uid 
not working at all
I tried in codepen example 
const dataLines = [
  { title: "One" },
  { title: "Two" },
  { title: "Three", noId: true }
]; to
const dataLines = [
  { title: "Zero" },
  { title: "One" },
  { title: "Two" },
  { title: "Three", noId: true }
];
key also changed 
https://codesandbox.io/s/kkmwr6vv47

Comment: @Isaac above anwser is fine for me ? because SakoBu
re-edited his anwser 
I think That's also fine for me with your this suggestion (stackoverflow.com/a/43892905/9816472)
componentWillMount() {
  let rows = this.props.rows.map(item => { 
    return {uid: SomeLibrary.generateUniqueID(), value: item};
  });
}

...

<tbody>
    {rows.map((row) => {
        return <ObjectRow key={row.uid} />;
    })}
</tbody>

Comment: @SubhajitPanja: Yes you can follow this updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What not to do

You should not be using **index** of the map for you **Key**, its an anti-pattern, it may lead to unpredictable results.

Please check this 
https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

> Right approach

You should be using proper **unique-id** for your Key, like a **DB id** or some unique-id.

This Key is used internally to identify the **DOM elements** to render and not to render again.